# How to use object declared inside custom jQuery plugin from another js file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a wrapper around `jquery DataTables` where I'll write my custom controls but I think that this problem is more related to `jQuery` than to something else.

In my `HTML` (view) I call my custom plugin like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#example').MyDataTable("some string");
    });
</script>
```

Then I extend the original `DataTables` API like so :

```
(function ($) {
  $.fn.MyDataTable = function (name) {

  //some code to get DataTables settings

  var oTable = $(this.selector).dataTable(options);

  //more code..        

  return this;
  }
}(jQuery));
```

I have another `.js` file which I include in the same page and I use to initialize my handlers. From this file I want to use `oTable` like so:

```
  $('#btnClearFilter').on('click', function () {
    console.log(oTable);
    oSettings = oTable.fnSettings();
```

I tried different ways to get the `oTable` obejct. Most of the time I get undefined. The only way that I could make it work is in the file where is my wrapper code to make this modification :

```
var oTable;
(function ($) {
    $.fn.bsDataTable = function (pageName) {
```

But I don't like the fact that I expose `oTable` like that and I think there's a pretty good chance to do that in a better way.

Comment: +1 good question, however it doesn't seem like you are instantiating `MyDataTable` at all on any selector?

Comment: @RobSchmuecker `MyDataTable` is more of a wrapper. What I really do is to instantiate the original `DataTable` - `var oTable = $(this.selector).dataTable(options);` but use this wrapper mostly to add custom `HTML` (for different filters - textboxes, dropdowns etc) and then use different `.js` files to set the handler for the different view. I don't know If this make sense, maybe there's a better way to do it. I just didn't want to end up with something like `$("#mydiv).dataTables(options).MyWrapper(options)...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make one global variable which is accessible in both the `.js` file, I had seen it in your question last part but define variable at in that `js` where you want to use it and set it from that plugin `.js`. I am sure you will get object from that variable.

Comment: Yeah, it works both ways. Do you think it's better. After all I'll have only one wrapper (where my gloabl is right now) and many external `.js` files  - one for each view. So I'll have to define it in each file. Not sure if this is improvement?

Comment: No you do not need to define it in all the file but you can make one common js file which will have list of variables and you just assign value to that variable and make them null after its use.